# What is wrong with my Haskell code?

Tags: haskell, ghci, hugs

My code:

```
addConcat :: [Int] -> [Int]
addConcat [x,y] = z:(z + y) where (z = x + y)
```

I'm implementing a function not exactly the one above but it's of the same format and I always get:

```
Syntax error in input (unexpected symbol "y")
```

So what is wrong with my Haskell code? I really need to use the 'where' clause but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the error you claim you get. If you are writing that code into a file and compiling it with `ghc` the error is:

```
<filename>.hs:2:38: parse error on input ‘=’
```

And the problem is that the syntax for `where` is wrong. Either write:

```
an_expression where z = x+y
```

Or you have to use **curly** braces:

```
an_expression where {z=x+y;}
```

You cannot use parenthesis to group an assignment.

Note that when writing in ghci you must group together the declarations and use a `let` to define functions:

```
Prelude> let {addConcat :: [Int] -> [Int]; addConcat [x,y] = [z,z+y] where z=x+y;}
Prelude> addConcat [1,2]
[3,5]
```

Note also that even fixing this your function still has a type error because the second argument of `:` must be a list while `z+y` is a number. You want `z:[z+y]` or more simply `[z, z+y]`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! the curly brace thing worked perfectly! You're awesome!